# Must a sequence of projections strongly converge to 0 if their values given by a faithful normal state converge to 0?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $\omega$ is a faithful normal state on a von Neumann algebra $R$, and $P_1, P_2, \ldots$ are projection operators in $R$ such that $\omega(P_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, must the $P_n$ converge to $0$ in the strong operator topology?

(Assuming $R$ has a separating vector, $R$'s faithful normal states are those induced by separating vectors, and the question is equivalent to: If $P_n v \rightarrow 0$ holds for some vector $v$ that is separating for $R$, must it hold for all vectors $v$?)

Comment: Yes, this is true. See Takesaki, Proposition III.5.3.

Comment: Fantastic, I found it, thank you! The proof is clever.

Answer (score 0):

If $\omega$ is a faithful, normal state then the GNS representation $(H_\omega,\pi_\omega)$ is a faithful, normal representation of $R$. Now the storng operator topology **depends** on the representation (in contrast to the ultraweak topology) but this is not an issue for us: normal (c.p.) maps are continuous with respect to the ultrastrong topologies and, since $p_n$ are projections (thus self-adjoint) we have that $p_n\to0$ strongly iff $\pi_\omega(p_n)\to0$ strongly.

So it suffices to show that $$\pi_\omega(p_n)\xrightarrow{SOT}0$$
But $(H_\omega,\pi_\omega)$ is a cyclic representation for $M$ and we have the canonical cyclic vector $\xi_\omega$. It is very easy to see that $H_\omega=\overline{\{x\xi_\omega:x\in\pi_\omega(M)'\}}$, i.e. that $\xi_\omega$ is also a cyclic vector for the commutant of $\pi_\omega(M)$.

Let $\eta\in H_\omega$. We will show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle\pi_\omega(p_n)\eta,\eta\rangle=0$ and from this we will conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi_\omega(p_n)\eta=0$, because
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|\pi_\omega(p_n)\eta\|^2=\lim_n\langle\pi_\omega(p_n)\eta,\pi_\omega(p_n)\eta\rangle=\lim_n\langle\pi_\omega(p_n)^2\eta,\eta\rangle=\lim_n\langle\pi_\omega(p_n)\eta,\eta\rangle=0.$$ Since $\eta$ was arbitrary, this will prove that $\pi_\omega(p_n)\to0$ strongly.

Now if $\varepsilon>0$ we find $x\in\pi_\omega(M)'$ so that $\|\eta-x\xi_\omega\|<\varepsilon$.

Now $$0\leq\langle\pi_\omega(p_n)x\xi_\omega,x\xi_\omega\rangle=\langle x^*x\pi_\omega(p_n)\xi_\omega,\xi_\omega\rangle\leq\langle \|x^*x\|\cdot1_{H_\omega}\cdot\pi_\omega(p_n)\xi_\omega,\xi_\omega\rangle=\|x\|^2\cdot\omega(p_n)\to0 $$

With a little housekeeping (one needs to write $\eta=\eta-x\xi_\omega+x\xi_\omega$ and do some Cauchy-Schwarz es), this will show that $\langle\pi_\omega(p_n)\eta,\eta\rangle$ becomes arbitrarily small while $n$ gets large, proving the claim.

I am posting this because I find Takesaki's book hard to read sometimes. I think this is more elementary than the approach presented there, but of course it is essentially the same.

Comment: I am not sure if that's what you meant in the first paragraph, but the strong operator topology coincides with the ultrastrong operator toplogy on norm bounded sets, and the latter does not depend on the (normal) representation.

Comment: @MaoWao well, sure, this is one way to see it; I am using the fact that the ultrastrong topology is independent of representation and the fact that, since $p_n$ are projections (thus self-adjoint) looking at them in the strong/ ultrastrong topology is the same.

Comment: @MaoWao I think I'm going to edit this to what you are saying, I guess it comes more naturally.